# google visualization change label on all values on x-axis

Tags: google-visualization

I have a bunch of products which I use ColumnChart to show the product name on the x-axis and then two different values that the products have on my y-axis. Since there are a bunch of products it gets pretty messy if I show all of them at once on the ColumnChart therefore I use the ChartRangeFilter Control to be able to have a window of products.

Now my problem is that ChartRangeFilter can't use strings on the axises. But I don't want to display the product id on the x-axis, so is it possible to change the lable when it is displayd? 
Hope you can understand what I mean. Below is some code to test in the [google code playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#chartrangefilter_control)

```js
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>
  Google Visualization API Sample
</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart', 'controls']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function drawVisualization() {
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
         document.getElementById('dashboard'));

     var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
       'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
       'containerId': 'control',
       'options': {
         // Filter by the date axis.
         'filterColumnIndex': 0,
         'ui': {
           'chartType': 'LineChart',
           'chartOptions': {
             'chartArea': {'width': '90%'},
             'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none'}
           },

           'chartView': {
             'columns': [0, 1, 2]
           },

           'minRangeSize': 1
         }
       },
       // Initial range: 1 to 4.
       'state': {'range': {'start': 1, 'end': 4}}
     });

     var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
       'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
       'containerId': 'chart',
       'options': {
         // Use the same chart area width as the control for axis alignment.
         'chartArea': {'height': '80%', 'width': '90%'},
         'hAxis': {'slantedText': false},
         'vAxis': {'viewWindow': {'min': 0, 'max': 20}},
         'legend': {'position': 'none'}
       }
     });

     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     data.addColumn('number', 'Product ID');
     data.addColumn('number', 'value1');
     data.addColumn('number', 'valu2');
     data.addRow([1, 11, 12]);
     data.addRow([2, 15, 12]);
     data.addRow([3, 10, 11]);
     data.addRow([4, 11, 9]);
     data.addRow([5, 8, 12]);
     data.addRow([6, 4, 9]);
     data.addRow([7, 8, 15]);
     data.addRow([8, 8, 11]);
     data.addRow([9, 8, 9]);


     dashboard.bind(control, chart);
     dashboard.draw(data);
  }


  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="dashboard">
    <div id="chart" style='width: 915px; height: 300px;'></div>
    <div id="control" style='width: 915px; height: 50px;'></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a DataView to get around this problem.  In the ControlWrapper, set the view.columns parameter like this:

```
var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
    'containerId': 'control',
    'options': {
        // Filter by the date axis.
        'filterColumnIndex': 0,
        'ui': {
            'chartType': 'LineChart',
            'chartOptions': {
                'chartArea': {'width': '90%'},
                'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none'}
            },
            'chartView': {
                'columns': [0, 1, 2]
            },
            'minRangeSize': 1
        }
    },
    // Initial range: 1 to 4.
    'state': {'range': {'start': 1, 'end': 4}},
    view: {
        columns: [{
            type: 'number',
            calc: function (dt, row) {
                return {v: row, f: dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0)};
            }
        }, 1, 2]
    }
});
```

then reverse the process in the ChartWrapper's view.columns:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
    'containerId': 'chart',
    'options': {
        // Use the same chart area width as the control for axis alignment.
        'chartArea': {'height': '80%', 'width': '90%'},
        'hAxis': {'slantedText': false},
        'vAxis': {'viewWindow': {'min': 0, 'max': 20}},
        'legend': {'position': 'none'}
    },
    view: {
        columns: [{
            type: 'string',
            label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
            calc: function (dt, row) {
                return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0);
            }
        }, 1, 2]
    }
});
```

That should get you what you want.

This code assumes you have a DataTable with 3 columns: a string (product name) and two number columns (value1 and value2).  Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/55agF/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not familiar with google visualizations and don't understand exactly what to do.
I have added the code inside my options in ControlWrapper and it still shows the same, but when I add the other part inside ChartWrapper the page gets completely white. 
I haven't added anything in my datatable. Should I not add the product names?

Comment: Thousand of "thank you very much"! I couldn't have solved it without your help!

Answer (score 0):

change the color of the text as of background

```
hAxis: {textStyle: {color: 'white'}},
```